# Can libxmp be forced to register a namespace prefix when it won't take a suggested prefix?

Tags: python, xmp

I'm handling xmp data with [python-xmp-toolkit](https://code.google.com/p/python-xmp-toolkit/), which is a python wrapping of the exempi C library.

We have an in-house namespace uri that we use in this data beginning with "ns:oursite.com" rather than "http:oursite.com" or something else similar. When I try to use the [register_namespace method](http://www.spacetelescope.org/static/projects/python-xmp-toolkit/docs/reference.html#libxmp.core.XMPMeta.register_namespace) to plug in our namespace like this:

> new_xmp.register_namespace("ns:oursite.com/stuff", "foo")

it spits back a default "ns2:" prefix indicating that it refuses to register the prefix I suggested.

I imagine it's doing some sort of validation on the uri name. Is there any way to force around this? I have a hard time deducing what to do in this code since it is a wrapping of C.

Comment: Just got bit by the same issue. Apparently there's a `DeleteNamespace()` method in the C++ Adobe SDK used by Exempi, itself used by python-xmp-toolkit. However it is not exposed to the Exempi C interface...

Answer (score 0):

There may be another namespace registered under the same prefix but with a different URI. Exempi allows neither duplicate namespaces nor duplicate prefixes, unfortunately, and this is a limitation of the underlying Adobe XMP SDK.

I found a workaround you could try to confirm it. The Exempi library can be reloaded through the Python bindings, but there is a very small amount of time (~100µs for me) during which another thread accessing Exempi *will* crash. Just run :

```
from libxmp import exempi

# Register a test namespace
exempi.register_namespace("http://test.com/test", "test")

# Release Exempi. Any XMP object initialized *before* this will be
# invalid and will segfault the interpreter...
exempi.terminate()

# Exempi is not initialized there, the Python interpreter will segfault
# if it is used. We have to call init() before being able to use it again.
exempi.init()

# Now you can register another URI with the same prefix
exempi.register_namespace("http://test.com/test/add", "test")
```